# I cannot paste stuff onto the stage with Gaia Framework

Tags: flash, gaia

I'm a total noob to Flash, and I'm learning it because I want to make a website design that looks like this.

[image: my proposed your actions design]

That's coming from a separate external .fla file not inside my Gaia project.

I currently have a **Gaia 3.2.6/FP10/AS3** project with **Timeline animation** that I just made up today.

The problem is that when I copy and paste those graphic symbols (not the background), into the 1st frame of my home.swf of my Gaia project, the preloader freezes at 50% on the home page.

When I remove the forms from my seperate external .fla file, then copy and paste them into the 1st frame of my Gaia project, the preloader freezes at 100%.

When I draw a square onto the first frame of home.swf, the page loads normally.

I'm putting the objects on a new layer on frame 1.
Please help me.

Comment: When you publish the file, do you get any Compile Errors in Flash?

Comment: No I don't. There's not even any warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using the **TLF Engine** (`TLF textfields`)? The Flash CS5 TLF Engine causes some errors when loading SWFs that wreak havoc on the Gaia Framework engine. You can read all about it in [this blog post by Steven Sacks](http://www.stevensacks.net/2010/05/28/flash-cs5-tlf-engine-causes-errors-with-loaded-swfs/), and in this [Adobe Technote](http://kb2.adobe.com/cps/838/cpsid_83812.html).

I think this might be your problem (I had the same happen to me and it drove me crazy for a few days). The solution is simple: Change your `TLF Textfields` to regular ones (it's labelled `Classic Text`, there is a selector on the TextField Properties panel) and (hopefully) everything will work fine.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help! Now all that needs fixing is the forms. How can I make the forms be able to work with Gaia?

Comment: So is the Gaia project loading normally now, with your graphic stuff? Were the problem the TLF textfields? As for the forms... it depends pretty much on what you want to do with them, but I think that's a completely different question ;) Make sure to read carefully all the Gaia documentation, as it is quite complete.

Comment: Yes the project loads normally now. The problem was the TLF textfields. However, when I insert a text box or button onto the stage and Publish, the preloader still freezes at 100%. I've read the Gaia documentation, and the forum is inactive.